# storing simple float on postgres loses percision

Tags: postgresql

I have a java application who stores a float in my postgres DB. 
I loose precision even though I do not do any computation . for example when I am storing the value 123.23, it stores 123.22999995

Why is that ?how can I avoid it

Comment: Single precision floating point numbers provide 6 significant digits of precision.

Comment: That's the nature of approximate data types like float or double. http://floating-point-gui.de/ Use `numeric` instead (and use `BigDecimal` in Java)